# gtk3 flowbox child 4px padding

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to find a way to get rid of the padding around GtkFlowBox children in PyGtk3.

Here is a minimal example which exhibits the 4px padding around each child.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk


window = Gtk.Window()

flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()

label0 = Gtk.Label("Test0")
label1 = Gtk.Label("Test1")

flowbox.add(label0)
flowbox.add(label1)

window.add(flowbox)

window.show_all()
window.connect('delete-event', lambda window, event: Gtk.main_quit())

print label0.get_allocated_height()
print flowbox.get_child_at_index(0).get_allocated_height()

Gtk.main()
```

Padding with flowbox;

http://forgottendream.org/~chasm/with_flowbox.png

Desired result without padding. (Default behavior with a GtkBox);

http://forgottendream.org/~chasm/with_box.png

Python version: 2.7.7
Gtk version: 3.12.2

EDIT: The following got rid of the extra space resulting in the same appearance as a GtkBox.

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

style_provider.load_from_data("""
GtkFlowBoxChild {
    padding: 0px;
}
GtkFlowBoxChild GtkLabel {
    padding: 0px;
}
""");

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
                                        style_provider,
                                        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually a padding of a widget is depends on Gtk.StyleContext () which is your gtk-theme. By default widget has allocated padding arounds it. Play with Gtk.StyleContext to get-set the padding. Or play with "margin"s property of Gtk.Widget. Personally this Gtk.FlowBox are utterly crap unless you want to filter-sort its children, who sorted and filter widgets?

Comment: I have already attempted to set various padding and margin attributes using the set_style method on the FlowBoxChild widgets, but I'll check out the Gtk.StyleContext.

I was looking for the reflowing behavior where the number of rows and columns changes to fit the dimensions of the container.